# When using deeplinks with ionic on android, always routed to rootpage

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, deep-linking

I am trying to build a mobile app with ionic (3.19.1), one of my needs is to have deep linking (routing) in the application.
I’ve followed ionic documentation and successfully created two pages, which can be routed by URL when using the chrome browser on my machine (ionic serve). When I am trying to deploy the application on an android device the routing is failed and root page is being opened.

Looking into it a bit more deeply, I noticed that once the application is opened on my android device (regardless if by clicking the app icon, or by external link leading to specific route in the application such as **myapp://www. myapp.com/#/oauthcallback/?oauth_token=Y&oauth_verifier=X**) the uri is **file:///andoid _assert/www/index.html** .

I understand that this is the location used by cordova to serve my app locally, yet in order to distinguish between different routes I must allow other urls (and specifically url parameters) to be passed to the application.

I’ve tried to play around with the application/urls but it didn’t yield any success, any idea will be welcomed!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

the reason it is redirect to the root page every time is because it matches the URL scheme of your app. Now why its not redirecting, it has two possibilities:

1. The route is not matching at all.
2. Even if the route matches, you have to navigate to the page in the callback function. to elaborate what i am saying following is the example.

`this.deeplinks.route({
                '/changePassword/:id': ChangePasswordPage
            }).subscribe((match) => {
                this.nav.setRoot(match.$route, {
                    id: match.$args.id
                })
                console.log('Successfully routed', match);
            }, (nomatch) => {
                console.log('Unmatched Route', nomatch);
            })`

To check whats really happening you can put some `console.log()` and inspect the app on device by using `chrome://inspect`, or if you don't know about that just put some alerts in the callbacks and see what you are getting.